# Problem with setting wallpaper in Google Launcher (antialiasing high res image)

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, gallery, wallpaper

I've made wallpaper in Photoshop. Original size is 1242x2208 (iPhone 6+ size). And imported to my phone, which has 480x854 (Android 5.0.2)
When I try to set wallpaper, preview looks good – but after setting I get this:

[image: preview] [image: wallpaper set]
<sup>Screenshots of preview and applied wallpaper (click images for larger variants)</sup>

After that, I tried to export my wallpaper in my device's size. No result. I've tried both `.png` and `.jpg` – but the applied wallpaper is always "crispy".

How to fix that?

Comment: I don't understand it – but maybe someone else does (might be either a language issue to a non-native, or my eyes are not good enough). I've integrated that with your question to make it easier to spot. So maybe we cleanup (remove) the comments now?

Comment: Your question has three close votes with "unclear" close reason and no comment explaining the problem in the question. Mind explaining to us what problem you are having, a bit differently. The wallpaper seems fine to me after being set on home screen.